Implementing Inkwell with onhover functionality on a button widget in flutter
I would like to implement hover functionality for a button.
I have a hover option in the code below but works only for mouse pointers.
The button code is as below
                Align(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, -1.0),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            child: FFButtonWidget(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                context.pushNamed('Books_Curriculum');
                              },
                              text: 'Curriculum',
                              options: FFButtonOptions(
                                width: () {
                                  if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointSmall) {
                                    return 300;
                                  } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointMedium) {
                                    return 600;
                                  } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointLarge) {
                                    return 700;
                                  } else {
                                    return 900;
                                  }
                                }()
                                    .toDouble(),
                                height: () {
                                  if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointSmall) {
                                    return 40;
                                  } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointMedium) {
                                    return 50;
                                  } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                      kBreakpointLarge) {
                                    return 60;
                                  } else {
                                    return 70;
                                  }
                                }()
                                    .toDouble(),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                iconPadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                color: Color(0xFFEFDB06),
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  fontSize: () {
                                    if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                        kBreakpointSmall) {
                                      return 20;
                                    } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context)
                                        .width <
                                        kBreakpointMedium) {
                                      return 24;
                                    } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context)
                                        .width <
                                        kBreakpointLarge) {
                                      return 28;
                                    } else {
                                      return 32;
                                    }
                                  }()
                                      .toDouble(),
                                ),
                                elevation: 3.0,
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                  width: 1.0,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                hoverColor: Colors.black,
                                hoverTextColor: Color(0xFFFCEC02),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

On hover the colour of button and text must interchange.
Currently the button colour is yellow and text is black
on hover the button colour must change to black and text to yellow



what do you mean by "but works only for mouse pointers."? how do you expect it to work?

On which platform do you want this on hover functionality to work? There is no such on hover event in Mobile.

@pskink .... the last part in the code " hoverColor: Colors.black, hoverTextColor: Color(0xFFFCEC02)," is an option available in flutterlow which works only for mouse pointers

@tomerpacific Kindly check out https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html
